# Understanding-- Convergence in Distribution does not imply convergence in PMF

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Rohatagi ch6 - example4----
I have two problems understanding this example. First, for convergence of PMF stated below

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables with PMF

$f_n(x) = P[X_n = x] = \begin{cases}1,\; if\; x =2+\frac{1}{n} \\ 0,  \;otherwise \end{cases}$

$f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ as $ n \rightarrow \inf $ , where $f(x) = 0$ for all x.

How it converges to $f(x)$ for all x as there will be atleast one x for which $f_n(x) = 1$

Second part of this example state that

$F_n(x)$ distribution functions of sequence $\{X_n\}$ converges to $F(x)$

where $F(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \; x<2\\ 1, x\ge 2\end{cases}$

How can $F_n(x)$ has equality sign at $2$ when $n \rightarrow \inf$.

Comment: Your first question is about [pointwise convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence).  Note $f(x)$ is not a probability mass function when $\sum_x f(x) \not = 1$.  Your second question is about [convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) and for $F(x)$ to be a cumulative distribution function, it must be left continuous

Comment: But $f_n(x)$ is not converging to $f(x)$ as $f_n(x)$ will be 1 for some $x$. But book states so.

Comment: ok, got it thanks ...for pointing towards right direction.